# java waiting for output command to finish in ProcessBuilder("sh")

Tags: java

How to wait for "cmd1" exit then run "cmd2" without using shell script.

```
    void exec(CharSequence ch) throws IOException {
        String string = ch.toString();
        out.write(string);
        out.newLine();
        out.flush();
        //Fix here.
    }

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("sh");
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    process = builder.start();
    out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));

    exec("sleep 5"); // cmd1
    exec("ls -al"); // cmd2
```

Answer (score 0):

`Process` has a method for this:

```
Process.waitFor()
```

Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this `Process` object has terminated.

Comment: sorry, waitFor() is wait for the subprocess called by java, but not wait for the process called by subprocess to be finish in outputstream.